# Debug maven mojo with eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse

I need to make a tool work inside maven (3.X) I am using mars/git for development of the mojo. This is what I have gathered so far:

*) debugging needs to be remote.

*) I would need to install the mojo in maven (with sources attached)  and have a dummy maven project that triggers the session.

Is this correct? Am I missing steps?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Selecting the "run-its" profile from the ide project's context menu allows me to at least launch the debug session. Let's see how far this takes me

Comment: But it does not attach any source to the debug session. The breakpoint is hit but no source path lookups work

Comment: checked the dynamic source lookup. It works

Answer (score 0):

See the comments above. And below

Selecting the "run-its" profile from the ide project's context menu allows me to at least launch the debug session. Let's see how far this takes me – efekctive Feb 20 at 23:25

But it does not attach any source to the debug session. The breakpoint is hit but no source path lookups work – efekctive Feb 20 at 23:33

checked the dynamic source lookup. It works.

Comment: If you answered your own question and you want to post an answer, make it a full, complete answer that's likely to help someone else.